# Hide unused wordpress custom field

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have a custom field that I need to keep for some posts but would like to hide when not used on others, slightly unsure how I can achieve this

**Custom field**

```
<div class="launch">    
<?php $description = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Launch", $single = true);
    if($description !== '') { echo $description; } ?>
</div><!-- /Launch -->
```

Comment: So what is the criteria form some post but not the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this.

```
<?php $description = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Launch", $single = true);
    if($description !== '') 
    { 
        echo '<div class="launch">';
        echo $description;
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```